# Finding shortest path between two nodes with a set of forbidden nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I have undirected and unweighted graph, in which I would like to find the shortest path between two entered nodes. There is also a set of forbidden nodes. How to find the shortest path, if I am allowed to visit **at most** one node from the set of forbidden nodes?

[image]

Comment: BFS, storing current node and if you already visited a forbidden node

Comment: @juvian This might not work even in the graph above. You cannot simply store a flag which determines if you already visited a forbidden node.

Comment: @Hawklike: please explain why you can't do that.  You're the *programmer*: you can store any state information you wish.  This is not a global flag: it's a flag associated with the node.  I agree that it won't work, but not for the reasons you state.

Comment: @Hawklike its a bit more complex, need a 2 level bfs. Still, posted a simpler answer for the case of only at most 1 forbidden node.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/101063/finding-shortest-path-between-two-nodes-with-a-set-of-forbidden-nodes

Comment: @Prune That's what I meant. I did not make myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do a BFS starting from END - Whenever it reaches a Forbidden node, update its distance_from_end and don't add its neighbors to your queue. All forbidden nodes that are not visited should not have a valid distance_from_end.
2. Do the same as (1) but starting from START and updating distance_from_start
3. For all forbidden nodes take the one with minimal distance_from_start + distance_from_end. (note that this node may not exist since nodes can have non valid values in those fields and thus should be disconsidered)
4. Do a BFS from start to finish, disconsider all forbidden nodes except the one found in (3).
5. From the BFS performed in 4 you'll either:

   - find a path that does not cross any forbidden node which is shorter than the one that would cross it.
   - find a path that does cross the forbidden node, in this case its length should be equal to (distance_from_start + distance_from_end) for that node.
   - find no path at all, meaning that you did not find a node in step (3) and that after removing all forbidden nodes from the graph, you get a graph where START and END are in different partitions.

Answer (score 1):

- Make a BFS from start, don´t go over forbidden nodes.
- Make a BFS from end, don´t go over forbidden nodes.
- Initialize path distance as dist(start, end). This will be infinite if your first bfs didn´t reach end.
- For each forbidden node, do path distance = min(path distance, dist(start, forbidden node) + dist(end, forbidden node))
- Return path distance

Complexity: same as BFS

Answer (score 0):

You can do a first BFS that list the reachable Forbidden nodes from start (but cannot cross it).
Then you record the distance from start. In your example 2 for each forbidden node.

You do the same from end node giving distances 2 and 1 on your path.

Then you unforbbid the best forbidden node (minimum distance from start+distance from end). And you finally do a BFS in the full graph.

You can eventually save the path to all forbidden nodes to save the last BFS.

Comment: What if there are more forbidden nodes in a path from start to end?

Comment: You mean having the right to cross for example 2 forbidden nodes ?

Comment: No, I mean for example a case, where two forbidden nodes would be in a row (or in a path from start to end). Because I am not sure about your determination which node to unforbid.

Comment: You cannot save the last BFS because the shortest path might not go through any forbidden node at all.

Comment: @Hawklike, you only consider forbidden nodes that can be reached from both edges when computing minimum distance, creating a global way with only 1 forbidden node.

Comment: @hbejgel Come on, this case can be checked during the two first BFS and its distance measured and compared to the minimum through forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a BFS, but with the graph as a parameter, rather than as a global reference table.  On any branch, when you visit a forbidden node, you stop and remove all of the *other* forbidden nodes from the graph you pass to the next level.

In fact, if you include a list of forbidden nodes as part of your graph structure, that removal can be a trivial iteration.

Comment: This is very interesting concept.